# TFS: How can I select one of my previous commit comments?

Tags: tfs, checkin

Often I'd like to use a previous commit comment (and edit e.g. just one word) for check-in.

I'm used to eclipse, where this feature works quite well.

Is it also available for TFS? I didn't find it yet (despite quick Web search), am I blind?
(I'm currently using TFS 2010 with VisualStudio 2010)

Best regards, Mayoares

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is anything in VS to help here (except cut and paste via change history).

However a little PowerShell with PSCX (PowerShell community Extensions) and the TFS PowerToys PowerShell snapin will do this, with the current folder set to the solution root:

```
(Get-TfsItemHistory . -recurse -stop 1).Comment | Set-Clipboard
```

will put the comment in the clipboard. Using the NuGet powershell session in TFS, this could likely be automated completely (left as exercise).

Comment: Thank you, Richard, that sounds good. I'll try to setup these helpers, when I have some more time.

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from @Richard for providing the crux to the solution--I have already upvoted his answer--but there is just a bit more to say here.

The OP was just slightly ambiguous: the title leaned toward the capability of selecting *some recent* commit message while the body was more suggesting to retrieve the *most recent* commit message. Richard addressed the latter perfectly, but I think it is worth commenting on the former as well.

Consider this function, which uses the same `Get-TfsItemHistory` from [TFS 2013 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) that Richard mentioned:

```
function Get-TfsComment([string]$pattern = ".*", [string]$Path = ".")
{
    Get-TfsItemHistory $Path -Recurse | ? { $_.Comment -match $pattern }
}
```

With that in place try:

```
# Get all comments
Get-TfsComment

# Get 10 latest comments
Get-TfsComment | Select -First 10

# Get all comments containing "bug" and "fix"
Get-TfsComment "bug.*fix"

# Get all comments in your tests folder containing "support"
Get-TfsComment -path .\tests -pattern support
```

The output of this function produces a collection of [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.aspx) objects; the list of default properties it displays are typically all you need:

```
Changes Owner               CreationDa Comment
   etId                             te
------- -----               ---------- -------
   1187 MYDOMAIN\fred        3/13/2014 Bug fixes for xyz...
   1118 MYDOMAIN\wilma        3/7/2014 New features 139 and 448
   1076 MYDOMAIN\barney      2/28/2014 Who remembers this...?
. . .
```

(Note that if you pipe the output to `FormatTable -AutoSize` that will take care of the poorly optimized line-wrap in the column headers.)